# Как пронумеровать совпадающие значения?

Tags: mysql, php, база-данных, sql

Вот такая задачка, не знаю даже в какую сторону смотреть, но почему-то уверен, что в запросе можно прописать как-то правило. Делаю запрос в БД, возвращается следующий набор данных (например):

> `39 А
> 40 А
> 41 Б9
> 42 А
> 43 Б9
> 44 В`

А хотелось бы, чтобы возвращался такой:

> `39 А(1)
> 40 А(2)
> 41 Б9(1)
> 42 А(3)
> 43 Б9(2)
> 44 В`

(39 .. 44 - уникальные ключи).

Можно ли непосредственно в запросе как-то это все провернуть?

Comment: Сначала подумал, что в скобках - это счетчик количества вхождений, потом понял, что это порядковый номер. Опишите, зачем это нужно, а то мне кажется, что вы смотрите не в ту сторону...

Comment: Виталий, второй столбец - короткое название для определенного "параграфа" в электронном учебнике. По одному параграфу может быть несколько тестов для получения квалификации.
В сводной таблице получаю:

Имя: Вася

Сдал тесты по след. параграфам: А(1) А(2) А(3) Б9(1) Б9(2) В

Т.е. сдал 3 теста по "параграфу" А, 2 теста по "параграфу" Б9 и 1 по параграфу В

Comment: врядли получится без извращений проще сделать в php либо типа A(39),A(40) в скобках указывать уникальный ключ

Comment: @Nikoole а почему не добавить столбец с позицией теста в параграфе? и его уже указывать в скобках, иначе у вас получается выборка тестов случайным порядком, и в случае изменения порядка тестов выданная ранее информация окажется недействительной.

Comment: FLK: слишком кардинальное решение... Важен номер теста в течении суток (к вечеру делают протокол ) - чтобы методист не запутался... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
create table T(a int primary key, b varchar(5));
insert into T values
(39, 'A'),
(40, 'A'),
(41, 'B9'),
(42, 'B'),
(43, 'B9'),
(44, 'A');
select a, concat(b,'(', (select count(*) from T t2 where t1.b=t2.b and t1.a >= t2.a),')')
from T t1;
```

[Нумерация записей в запросе](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_numbering_rows_in_query.html)

Comment: msi: а если повторений нет - выведется, например, А(0) - можно как-то исключить это? (: (в любом случае огромное спасибо за решение)

Comment: Такое невозможно. 0 -- значит 'А' в поле b вообще нет, и такой строчке взяться неоткуда. Это было бы возможно при условии `t1.a > t2.a` вместо `t1.a >= t2.a`

Comment: alexlz: Вот по примеру пользователя msi: для (42, 'B') выведется В(1)
а надо просто В, в то же время для В9, раз их два, должно вывестись В9(1) и В9(2).

Comment: Ужас. А если

        select a, case (select count(*) from T t2 where t1.b=t2.b)
            when 1 then b 
            else concat(b,'(', (select count(*)
                    from T t2 where t1.b=t2.b and t1.a >= t2.a),')')
                 end
         from T t1;

Можно не case, а if(...)

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL нет натуральной сортировки. Можно сортировать через преобразование в число, но - это проктологический метод. Натуральная сортировка [есть в PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.natsort.php). Делаешь запрос, а результат сортируешь в PHP.

Comment: @KiTE подозреваю, что вопрос не в сортировке, а в выводе. и надо указывать порядковый номер совпавших элементов.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, то он хочет не отсортировать, а вывести в скобках порядковый номер вхождения. Хотя возможно я ошибаюсь...

Comment: Не могу разобраться, как применить эту функцию для решения моей задачи... Мне надо в случае совпадения строки, добавить к ней ее номер по порядку.

Comment: Да, верно. Ответил до того как была отформатирована первая версия вопроса. А там это было непонятно.

По сути вопроса: простым запросом - нельзя. Можно извернуться через хранимку которая сгенерит временную таблицу, но оно того не стоит. Лучше на уровне PHP